# Additional CSS in Wordpress Not working, is my syntax wrong?

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, font-size

i am modifying the font size of a page, [link:https://positivehk.com/2021/03/01/英國食好西-milkandmore/](https://positivehk.com/2021/03/01/%E8%8B%B1%E5%9C%8B%E9%A3%9F%E5%A5%BD%E8%A5%BF-milkandmore/)

At the bottom, there is a session with title "你可能感興趣：", and under it are some suggested links. These are the session i wanna change the font size.
[image]

I tried this:

```
.post header .entry-title {word-wrap: break-word; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px;  !important}
```

and this:

```
.entry-header.entry-title a { word-wrap: break-word; font-size: 16; line-height: 20px; !important}
```

in the Advanced > Additional CSS class(es), which is located at the bottom right column of the block. But it doesn't work.

Would anyone please tell me how should i do it? I find it weird as I edit the code in the browser, the additional CSS works; but when i put it in the Wordpress additional CSS area, save it and refresh, it doesn't work.

**update: i tried these**

```
.entry-title {word-wrap: break-word; font-size: 16px; line-height: 18px;  !important}
```

and

```
.loop-entry .entry-header .entry-title a {word-wrap: break-word; font-size: 16px; line-height: 18px;  !important}
```

But they seem not working.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tPGYk8Eyrdm8PaSA1u0Vzim8jke8BpU7/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

try removing .post header in selecter or don't add any space in .post header use post-header as ID

Comment: like this? .post-header { word-wrap: break-word; font-size: 16; line-height: 20px; !important}

Comment: yes,like this.Also change the html id code to id="post-header"

Comment: i am sorry, how do i do that? as i am using a plugin called Kadence, it has this preset block i can use along with the original Gutenberg. So, i am not too sure now to add the id="post-header" to the original html. Would you please let me now how?

Comment: You can do one more thing,that just type .entry-title as the selector

Comment: Sadly, it is not working.... why is it so sturdy? Does the plugin forbid the change?

Answer (score 0):

i try this and it should work fine

```
.loop-entry .entry-header .entry-title a {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: blue;
}
```

**post.style.build.css**
[image]

**style.css**
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Daniel, I put this ".loop-entry .entry-header .entry-title a {word-wrap: break-word; font-size: 16px; line-height: 18px;  !important} " into the additional CSS , but it seems not working.

Comment: i edit post and add a 2 picture, try to find the correct css file

Answer (score 0):

The field "additional CSS classes" in the extended block settings is **not** intended for CSS rules (i.e. class names and their parameters/settings), but only to apply a CSS class to that particular block!

To add settings for an already existing class (as you tried apparently) you should either use an external style sheet (if you wrote the wordpress theme yourself), or add those in the "additional CSS" section of the "customizer".